# How do I extrude a flat image using Blender?

Tags: modeling, svg

**How to create an extruded image using Blender?**

Started with Inkscape and created the following .svg file:

[image]

Then I tried to import the above .svg file via the Import menu and via drag-and-drop and nothing showed up.

Saw its name "player_inkscape.svg" in the Outliner:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried importing flat .png file into Blender as an image empty.

I am using an extruded image in a game - imagine looking down on a person as they turn on their z-axis as the person follows a moving object with their eyes. There is standard Swift library code that will do that. I just need the .svg file consisting of a Croquet Player that hits the ball and then turns their body as the ball goes in different directions.

As a Player looks at a ball going to their left, they will rotate in such way that you now see their right shoulder, if the Player follows with their eyes a ball going to their right, you will suddenly see their left shoulder, if a Player follows a ball going behind them, you will see their back.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146001/discussion-on-question-by-john-how-to-create-an-extruded-image-using-blender); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: It seems you misunderstand the workflow of making images of a character for a game. Maybe someone could provide an answer related to that. One needs to create a 3d model of a character using various 3d modelling techniques in order to be able to animate it turning around. Simply extruding an image will not produce a 3d model sufficient to achieve good results(not until AI does it after stealing all our jobs anyway :D (might be any time now :D )) Which might be a good point - you might want to check Stable Diffusion out if you have a decent graphics card...

Comment: ...or maybe [DragGAN](https://github.com/XingangPan/DragGAN). See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPI2jGvxEM4

Comment: I remember in the mid 70's, watching a short video of the original, very alive, Walt Disney on TV (B&W). He was demonstrating how his ingenious cartoon makers (e.g., Tom and Jerry) draw frame after frame of just one character. Each frame was sketched on a real paper tablet sized about 3 ft by 3 ft. Those magicians could hand draw one frame in about 60 seconds - then onto the next frame - until, each of the 30 tablet sheets was full. THEN, someone would take the tablet & grab the top with one hand & thumb thru each page very rapidly. MAGIC .. Tom and Jerry moved. Image was extruded. YES!.

Comment: AH .. the days of Lady and the Tramp (finally, in living Color - TechNColor).  Then, color was considered a awesome invention